# Activator is not starting after exporting the eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am new to Eclipse plugin development and I have just completed development of my 1st plugin.

It's running without any issues, when I run the project as an "Eclipse Application". So I exported the plugin and installed it to another distribution of eclipse. But now it's not working as I expected.

Inside my `activator.start()` I added few even listeners and neither of them are getting triggered. Later I found this `start()` method is not fired after I export the product.

To make sure, I used `MessageConsoleStream` and print something to the console.
Again this is working in the development time, but not in the exported version.

But the view of the plugin is displayed without any problems.

What has gone wrong?

*Eclipse version : 4.4.2*

Comment: Activators are not normally started until something else in the plugin is used. They are not the place to add listeners. What do you want to listen for?

Comment: I need to add a `Resource Change Listener`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Activators are not normally started until something else in the plugin is used. They are not the place to add listeners.

If you want to start listening to something when Eclipse starts use the `org.eclipse.ui.startup` extension to declare an early start up class

```xml
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.startup">
  <startup class="package.StartupClass"/>
</extension>
```

The start up class implements `org.eclipse.ui.IStartup`

Comment: @greg-449 is it possible to listen to a plugin Activator's errors from another plugin Activator

Comment: @AbdelRahmane I don't know what you mean by 'a plugin Activator's errors'. If you have a question please ask a Question.

Comment: @greg-449 I mean when one of it's methods is called like Activator.logError (..) . I taught that it is related to this question.

Comment: @AbdelRahmane You need to ask a question, comments are not appropriate for this.

Comment: @greg-449 Ok here is the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45576195/custom-errors-in-eclipse-rcp-application