# Custom errors in Eclipse RCP application

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I was looking for a way to provide users of an RCP application customized errors that will help them understand what causes some runtime errors. I created a custom Problems view and I create a marker each time an error occur. I'm showing in this view only markers of a custom marker type that are related to an annotation.

My questions:

1-Is there a better approach then this one ?

2-How to handle the errors that occur in a core plugin ? Is there a way to be notified in a ui plugin when an Activator method is called (like Activator.logError (..) ...) in a core plugin ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can listen to logging events on the Eclipse log by calling:

```
Platform.addLogListener(listener);
```

where `listener` implements `org.eclipse.core.runtime.ILogListener`.

Comment: Is it possible with this solution to have extra information that are not contained in a Status object?

Comment: The logging uses the `IStatus` interface so it can be anything implementing that. There are already classes such as `MultiStatus` which support nested Status objects.

Comment: Thank you very much